# PHP if statement, does not validate, only first if runs

Tags: php

I have 3 stages to my if statement.
If is front page return true. 
If is not front page but object is set and has certain value return true.
If not return false.

It worked as two seperate statement, 
1) if is front page return true if not false
2) if object is set and has given value return true, objects is not set type return false.

When I try to put them as one statement I get true if front page but this rest doesn't return.

Code is below. Is their anything wrong with the statement? Thanks

```
<?php
$object = get_object();

if(is_front())
{
  return 'true'; 
} 
elseif (!(is_front() & !empty($object))) //is not front but object has been set check value
{
  confirm_value();
}
else (!(is_front() & empty($object))) //if not front and object is not set
{
  return 'false';
}

function confirm_value() {
  $value = load($object); //load object
  if($value->id($id)) //check value of id
  {
    return 'true';  
  } 
  else
  {
    return 'false'; 
  }
}
?>
```

working code below

```
<?php
$object = get_object();

if(is_front())
{
  return 'true'; 
} 
elseif (!(is_front() && !empty($object))) //is not front but object has been set check value
{
  return confirm_value();
}
else 
{
  return 'false';
}

function confirm_value() {
  $value = load($object); //load object
  if($value->id($id)) //check value of id
  {
    return 'true';  
  } 
  else
  {
    return 'false'; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Too many parens, and use of `&` instead of `&&`...

Comment: since you check is_front() in the 1st if,  no need to check it again in the eleseif and else branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I see:

## 1 - you are using a single & when you should be using &&.

## 2

```
confirm_value();
```

should be

```
return confirm_value();
```

Comment: It was return, so the second wasn't running. have updated answer to show working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the aim of code above but:

- Use `return confirm_value();`
- Else statement do not have condition. If you want check condition you should continue using elseif
- Should using && instead of &. Because of & is bitwise operator. It will same result with && when all conditions are boolean. But when 1
  & 2 == false

Comment: Thanks, accepted another answer as it came first. but this was also helpful